# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{99}C(100,k)4^{k+2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Evaluate the following sum and show your work. Leave expressions of the form ݉$m^n$ in your 
answer without attempting to evaluate them. Solutions that rely solely on calculator 
computation of the 100 terms of the sum are unacceptable.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{99} C(100,k)4^{k+2}$$

Please verify my answer below, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions to improve the readability or quality of my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum to be computed is $$\sum_{k=1}^{99} {100 \choose k}4^{k+2}$$

The Binomial theorem states that

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n { n \choose k} x^k y^{n-k} =x^n+y^n+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n \choose k}x^ky^{n-k}$$

For $n=100$, $x=4$ and $y=1$, this yields
$$\sum_{k=1}^{99} {100 \choose k}4^{k+2}=16\sum_{k=1}^{99} {100 \choose k}4^{k}1^{n-k}=16\left((4+1)^{100}-4^{100}-1\right)$$
that is, $$\sum_{k=1}^{99} {100 \choose k}4^{k+2}=16\left(5^{100}-4^{100}-1\right)$$

---

To verify the accuracy of my answer, I plugged the original summation into a calculator.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{99} {100 \choose k}4^{k+2}
=126217744809650880157732726036574403270254427977088432862719943541427968$$
Then compared it to my answer,
$$16[5^{100}-4^{100}-1]
=126217744809650880157732726036574403270254427977088432862719943541427968$$

Comment: +1, this is correct (except that $1^n$ should read $1^{100}$ once and $x$ should read $4$ twice).

Comment: $16[-1^{\color{red}{100}}+\sum...$ Here correct? Also, what do you mean by twice? in $x^k$?

Comment: @mar10, Have you noticed $x^k$ and $x^{100}$ after "So,"?

Comment: Yes of course, ah I see; You mean change x => 4  ; I left it there to show how my process relates back to the Binomial theorem, I will edit this now. Let me know how it looks, Please. Changes will be blue.

Comment: @Did Sorry to bug you, How does it look now? I think I have made the necessary changes.

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{99} {100 \choose k}4^{k+2}$$

$$=4^2\left[\sum_{k=1}^{99} {100 \choose k}4^k\right]$$

$$=4^2\left[-{100 \choose 0}4^0-{100 \choose 100}4^{100}+\sum_{k=0}^{100} {100 \choose k}4^k\right]$$

Using Binomial Expansion formula,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{100} {100 \choose k}4^k=(1+4)^{100}$$

Comment: That is very similar to my first attempt at this problem! Except my first attempt using expansion failed, Thank you for this!

Comment: @mar10, You don't need to supply numerical steps. Btw, has the similarity caused the down-vote?

Comment: Numerical steps --> Do you mean the part directly after "So,"? My apologies, I did not down-vote you, I did give you an up-vote however :)

Comment: @mar10, I mean the verification. Sorry,  I actually want to get my mistake getting recognized & rectified.

Comment: Oh Yes, the verification I put there for myself, I would normally not include this. I noticed you removed $4^2[-1-4^{100}+(1+4)^{100}]$